# What is the correct condition for $y=f(x)$ to be symmetrical about $x=a$? $f(x-a)=f(x+a)$ or $f(-x+a)=f(x+a)$?

Tags: functions

What is the correct condition for $y=f(x)$  to be symmetrical about $x=a$?

- $f(x-a)=f(x+a)$ or
- $f(-x+a)=f(x+a)$?

## Attempt

For the first case, let $a$ be a constant and $x$ be a variable.

|---------------|---------------|

x-2a-----------a---------------x

\begin{align}
f(x-2a)&=f(x)\\
f(x+a-2a)&=f(x+a)\\
f(x-a)&=f(x+a)
\end{align}

For the second case, let $f(x)$ be an even function which is asymmetrical about $x=0$.

Translating with vector $(a,0)$ will make the graph symmetrical about $x=a$, so I have
\begin{align}
f(-x)&=f(x)\\
f(-(x-a))&=f(x-a)\\
f(-x+a)&=f(x-a)
\end{align}
The end result is not $f(-x+a)=f(x+a)$. I am confused. Please help.

Comment: the second one.

Comment: See what each of those mean in simple cases, for example $a=0$ or $a=1$.

Comment: The second one is saying that if you take $a$ and move it to the right by $x$ (subtracting x ) gives the same value of $f$ as taking $a$ and moving to the left (adding $x$). That's what you want.

Comment: If someone wanted to be really annoying. They'd say the first one was correct if $a$ is the variable and $x$ is fixed.

Comment: can't you also use polar coordinates and also the properties of being symmetric.

Comment: @StupidIsAsStupidDoes After the edits: for the first case, you (correctly) got $f(x-2a)=f(x)$ which is the condition for $f$ to be periodic with period $2a$. This has nothing to do with symmetries.

Comment: For the second case, you got the translation backwards. In order to move the axis of symmetry $0 \mapsto a$ you must use the substitution $x \mapsto x+a$, then $f(-x)=f(x)$ becomes $f(-x+a)=f(x+a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)$ is symmetric about $x=a$ iff $f(x')=f(x'')$ for all points $x',x''$ symmetric about $a$ on the $x$ axis. The latter condition is equivalent to the midpoint $\frac{x'+x''}{2}$ of the segment between $x',x''$ being $a$, which can be written as $x'+x''=2a \iff x''=2a-x'$, so in the end the condition is $f(x')=f(2a-x')$. With $x=a-x'$ the condition becomes $f(a-x)=f(a+x)$, which matches the second one in the posted question.

Below are some comments on the original post.

> For the first case, let $a$ be a constant and $x$ be a variable.
>
> x-2a-----------a---------------x

The diagram is wrong. If the endpoints are $x-2a$ and $x$ then the midpoint is $\frac{x-2a+x}{2}=x-a$, not $a$.

> $f(x-2a)=f(x)$

This is indeed equivalent to the first condition, and it means that $f(x)$ is periodic with period $2a$. This is unrelated to symmetries about $x=a$.

> For the second case, let $f(x)$ be an even function which is symmetrical about $x=0$ [...]

This is harder to follow if using the same $f(x)$ notation to refer to both the original function and the translated (even) one.

Using different names for the two functions, consider that $f(x)$ is symmetric about $x=a$ iff $g(x)=f(x+a)$ is even. That means $g(x)=g(-x) \iff f(x+a)=f(-x+a)\,$.

Comment: I see. My wrong diagram is a culprit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry means $f(a-x)=f(a+x), \forall ~ x \in R.$
One may also shift $x \to a-x$, then
the condition also becomes
$$f(2a-x)=f(x), \forall x ~ \in R$$